# Find the invariant polynomial space of a finite matrix group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, invariant-theory

This is an exercise from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al.

Denote the finite matrix group $\{\pm I_2\}\subset GL(2,k)$ by $C_2$. It is known that the invariant polynomials under $C_2$ can be written as polynomials of $x^2,xy,y^2$. Hence we can denote this space by $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$.

> The exercise asks to find the invariant polynomial space under $C_6$, a cyclic finite matrix group generated by 
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
>   using the fact that this space is in $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ which I have proved, and the fact
>   $$k[x_1,\dots,x_n]^G=k[R_G(x^{\beta}):|\beta|\leq |G|)]$$ 
>   where $R_G(f)$ is the Reynold operator acting on $f$ under the group $G$.

So in this case I calculated the Reynolds operator acting on $x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,\dots,x^6,x^5y,x^4y^2,x^3y^3,x^2y^4,xy^5,y^6$.

I found out the following polynomials (I omitted the ones that wouldn't give any new generators):
$$x^2-xy+y^2\\
(x-y)^6+x^6+y^6\\
x^5y+ x(x - y)^5 - y^5(x - y)\\
x^4y^2 + x^2(x - y)^4 + y^4(x - y)^2\\
x^3y^3 + x^3(x - y)^3 - y^3(x - y)^3\\
x^2y^4 + x^4(x - y)^2 + y^2(x - y)^4\\
xy^5 + x^5(x - y) - y(x - y)^5\\
(x - y)^6 + x^6 + y^6$$

Since these don't generate $x^2$, this space is included in $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$, but not equal to it. So I have to find some generators. I tried combinations of $x^2,xy,y^2$, for example, $x^2-xy+y^2, x^2-xy$, or $x^2-xy,y^2-xy$, and many others, nothing works.

I hope I made myself clear about this problem. 
Can anyone suggest a set of generators? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, assume that $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero. If $C_n\subset Gl_2(k)$, a cyclic group of order $n$ and $\sigma$ a generator, one can diagonalize it and thus assume $\sigma$ has diagonal entries $\omega^i,\omega^j$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $n^{\rm{th}}$ root of unity and $i,j,n$ have no common factors. Then the action is given by $\sigma(x)=\omega^ix, \sigma(y)=\omega^jy$ and thus the invariants are given by $x^ay^b$ where $ai+bj$ is divisible by $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This seems like a very simple method. After you diagonalize $\sigma$, say, $\sigma=P^{-1}DP$, I understand why $D$ must have diagonal entries $\omega^i,\omega^j$. But how can we ignore the $P$ and $P^{-1}$? For an invariant $f$, we have $f(\sigma(x))=f(x)$ or $f(P^{-1}DP x)=f(x)$. Is it equivalent to $f(Dx)=f(x)$? Why?

Comment: No, action of $P$ will just change $x,y$ to $x',y'$ suitable linear combinations of $x,y$. But, one can act by $P$ to get back everything in $x,y$ if you wish, though it looks better in $x',y'$ and any property you wish can be read at that level.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean but couldn't construct it by examples. For example, let $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $D=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Suppose we do $f(Px)=f(x-y,y)$. Then apply $D$ we get $f(2x-2y,y)$. Applying $P^{-1}$ gives then $f(2x-y,y)$. It is confusing to me how to connect this with the invariant of $f$ under $D$. Could you explain your $x',y'$ using this example? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. $D$ does not have finite order in your example.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Let $D=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ then. If $f$ is invariant under $P^{-1}DP$, then $f(x,y)=f(-x+2y,y)$. But how does it imply $f(\vec{x}')=f(D\vec{x}')$? What are the $x',y'$ in this case?